# Mystery "it works" message on port 8080 - no web server installed

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux, port

I'm running Arch. I don't have Apache or any other web server installed. Accessing `localhost:8080`, I get a plaintext response:

```
it works
```

No HTML, nothing. I don't know what process is serving this. `lsof -i :8080` gives nothing, as does `ps aux | grep 8080`, as does `ss -ap | grep 8080`.

How can I find what process is providing this and terminate it?

Comment: What nftables or iptables rules do you have?

Comment: What's the output of `netstat -tulpn | grep 8080`? Please don't answer in comments, but [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1770945/edit) your question instead. That way all the relevant info is readily available.

Comment: @Peregrino69 done. it showed lighttpd. problem solved, and I added it as an answer (unfortunately I can't accept it yet and have to wait 2 days). thank you for your help :)

Comment: You's most welcome :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After installing `netstat` and running `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 8080`, I get:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      661/lighttpd
```

I can then `sudo systemctl stop lighttpd` and the issue is solved.

Thanks to [@Peregrino69](https://superuser.com/users/330527/peregrino69) for pointing me to this.